# How to change dataframe column names without changing the values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of CSV files which are read as dataframes. For each dataframe, I want to change some column names, if a specific column exists in a dataframe:

column_name_update_map = {'aa': 'xx'; 'bb': 'yy'}

In such a map, if 'aa' or 'bb' exists in a dataframe, I want to change the aa to xx, and 'bb' to 'yy'. No values should be changed.

```
  for file in files:
        print('Current file: ', file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')
        df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
        for index, row in df.iterrows(): 

           pass
```

I don't think I should use the inner loop, but if I have to do, what's the right way to change the column name only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) in dataframes

```
column_name_update_map = {'aa': 'xx', 'bb': 'yy'}
df = df.rename(columns=column_name_update_map)
```

Comment: No, 'aa' and 'bb' are only two columns, not all the columns in the df. Would this still work?

Comment: Abigail your question needs more clarification. Please mention which column names you want to change.  If you looking for the unnamed column '' to 'NaN',  then you can opt that in the replace() mapping.

Comment: yes,dictionary keys are your old column names and values are new column names.

Comment: I mean if there are 8 columns in the df, and I only need to change 2 of them. Is that still working?

Comment: It works. You have to opt the parameter 'inplace=True'. Just try the code.

Comment: you can use  'inplace=True'  or assign to same dataframe without inplace parameter.

Comment: This one works and I like its simplifity

Answer (score 2):

To rename specific columns then follow this code.

> Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#creating sample dataframe 
df=pd.DataFrame({'aa':[1, 2], 'bb':[3, 4], 'c':[5, 6], '':[7, 8]})

#replace columns 'aa' to 'xx', 'bb'  to 'yy' and '' to 'NaN'
df.rename(columns={'aa':'xx', 'bb':'yy', '':np.nan}, inplace=True)
#display resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: Sorry it was rename() function.

Comment: Does it worked?